# SQL Join with line items

Tags: mysql, join

I need to join an invoice table to a license table.

Every license has has one invoice, but an invoice can have multiple line items.  So license X can have invoice Y with line item 1 and 2 (the line items create separate rows).

If I try to left join the license table to the invoice table like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table.Invoice I LEFT JOIN table.License L    
ON I.ClientID = L.ClientID;
```

some of the rows repeat information, but for different licenses.  The rows are unique but they are not correct.  So for example, these would be my incorrect results:

```
Invoice #: 1 LicenseID: X Line item: 1    
Invoice #: 1 LicenseID: Y Line item: 1    
Invoice #: 2 LicenseID: X Line item: 1    
Invoice #: 2 LicenseID: Y Line item: 1    
Invoice #: 2 LicenseID: X Line item: 2    
Invoice #: 2 LicenseID: Y Line item: 2
```

The true result should be something like this:

```
Invoice #: 1 LicenseID: X Line item: 1    
Invoice #: 2 LicenseID: Y Line item: 1    
Invoice #: 2 LicenseID: Y Line item: 2
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve these results?  How can I join these two tables (clientID is the only thing they have in common) so that I don't get repeating information?

Comment: Please provide the table structure and also provide the details how your first result set is incorrect and second is correct? On what base did you compress 6 results to 3 results?

Comment: Table structure is this: INVOICE: InvoiceID, Invoice#, Line item, ClientID.   The LICENSE table has these rows: LicenseID, ClientID.   The first set of results is incorrect because License Y matches with Invoice #2.  License X matches with Invoice #1.  Invoice #2 has two line items, and each line item gets it's own row.  I am matching the tables on ClientID

Comment: I see no problem with your query then: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70bb1/2. pretty sure the problem is your data. so you have same `invoiceid, invoiceN and clientId` for each of different `lineItem` ?? Why do you need 2 columns `InvoiceId` and `Invoice #` ?

Comment: Alex, I do think that there is a problem with the data.  But I'm looking for a way to create the datasource without having to change the data structure

Comment: you are looking for something you can't describe properly

Comment: Alex, to answer your questions, yes that is how the table is set up.  Same invoiceid, invoiceN, and clientId for each of the different lineItems.  It is necessary to have 2 columns InvoiceID and invoice # because 1 Invoice ID can have multiple line items.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random guess, you ask for `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table.Invoice I LEFT JOIN table.License L    
ON I.ClientID = L.ClientID;
```

Comment: The problem is, the rows ARE distinct.  If you look at the first set of results, the rows are unique but it is matching each license with each invoice that a client has, even if the invoice and license don't match.  Thanks for the answer though.